# How to make a external API call inside express server?

Tags: node.js, api, express, onesignal

Hello I ve been trying to implement OneSignal API on my dashboard and I wonder if it is possible to make a API external call inside express server.

Here is an example:

```
var sendNotification = function(data) {
  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization": "Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj"
  };

  var options = {
    host: "onesignal.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/api/v1/notifications",
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers
  };

  var https = require('https');
  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log("Response:");
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("ERROR:");
    console.log(e);
  });

  req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
  req.end();
};
```

Here it is the app route

```
app.post('/path', function(req, res){


var message = { 
  app_id: "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
  contents: {"en": "English Message"},
  included_segments: ["All"]
};

sendNotification(message);
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

> I wonder if it is possible to make a API external call inside express
>   server.

Sure, you can contact any external server from a node.js app with `http.request()` like you are showing or one of the higher level modules built on top of that like the [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

Here's a simple example from the request module home page:

```
const request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
});
```

Or, using promises:

```
 const rp = require('request-promise');
 rp('http://www.google.com').then(body => {
     console.log(body);
 }).catch(err => {
     console.log(err);
 });
```

---

**EDIT Jan, 2020 - request() module in maintenance mode**

FYI, the `request` module and its derivatives like [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) are now in maintenance mode and will not be actively developed to add new features.  You can read more about the reasoning [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode).  There is a list of alternatives in [this table](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode#alternativestorequest) with some discussion of each one.  I have been using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself and it's built from the beginning to use promises and is simple to use.

Answer (score 14):

you can use Axios client as Axios is a Promise based HTTP client for the browser as well as node.js.

Using Promises is a great advantage when dealing with code that requires a more complicated chain of events. Writing asynchronous code can get confusing, and Promises are one of several solutions to this problem.

First install Axios in your application using `npm install axios --save`

and then you can use this code

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get('api-url')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data.status);
        // console.log(response.data);
        res.send(response.data.status);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly try out this solution. i used it and it worked for me.

```html
var Request = require("request");

Request.get("http://httpbin.org/ip", (error, response, body) => {
    if(error) {
        return console.dir(error);
    }
    console.dir(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `request-promise-native` that uses native ES6 promises.

Install the request-promise-native package

```
npm install --save request
npm install --save request-promise-native
```

Use it as follows :

```
const request = require('request-promise-native');

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'https://www.google.com'
}

request(options).then(response => {
    console.log(response);
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**2022 update**

Built in fetch api is available in NodeJS 18+. Third party npm modules are no longer needed.

```
(async () => {
    const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products/1')
    if (res.ok) {
        const data = await res.json()
        console.log(data)
    }
})()
```

More details in the official [blog](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/#fetch-experimental)